# How to align these two tikz figures better?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I'm quite new to latex and I'm trying to get two tikz figures side by side. I've honestly just looked up "tikz figures side by side" and taken code and re-adjusted it to give the figures I want, so parts of the below code might seen unnecessary.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.55,tdplot_main_coords]
\filldraw[
    draw=gray,
    fill=gray!40,
]          (1,1,0)
        -- (0,1,0)
        -- (0,-1,0)
        -- (1,-1,0)
        -- cycle;
\draw[thin,->] (-1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1,0);
\draw[thin,->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thin,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The cone $\sigma$}
\end{subfigure}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.55,tdplot_main_coords]
\filldraw[
    draw=gray,
    fill=gray!40,
]          (1,0,1)
        -- (1,0,-1)
        -- (0,0,-1)
        -- (0,0,1)
        -- cycle;
\draw[thin,->] (-1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[thin,->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thin,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The dual cone $\sigma^*$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{$Cone((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,-1,0))$ and its dual cone.}
\end{figure}
```

This creates the figure like so;

[image]

I have a small gripe though. The bottom of the z-axis on the left picture isn't in line with the bottom of the z-axis on the right. It would just be neater to me if they were aligned, but I can't figure out how to. Any help?

Comment: Hi, I think that adding the parameter `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]` or `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(0,0,0)]` to both of them should help. Or maybe not, since they're subfigures... :-/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It's always nice if you create a minimal, yet complete example -- a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) -- rather than just a snippet. That way people don't have to figure out which packages are required. On another note, perhaps you want `\hfill` or e.g. `\hspace{3cm}` rather than `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following idea:

- measure the height of the larger picture
- put the smaller picture in a `vbox` that has the same height as the larger picture and use `vfill` to get the vertical alignment you wish.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

\sbox{\tempbox}{%
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.55,tdplot_main_coords]
        \filldraw[
            draw=gray,
            fill=gray!40,
        ]          (1,0,1)
        -- (1,0,-1)
        -- (0,0,-1)
        -- (0,0,1)
        -- cycle;
        \draw[thin,->] (-1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
        \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1);
        \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
        \draw[thin,->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
        \draw[thin,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        % for the other figures, you can use \vfill as follows
        \vbox to\ht\tempbox{
            \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.55,tdplot_main_coords]
                \filldraw[
                    draw=gray,
                    fill=gray!40,
                ]          (1,1,0)
                -- (0,1,0)
                -- (0,-1,0)
                -- (1,-1,0)
                -- cycle;
                \draw[thin,->] (-1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
                \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
                \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
                \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1,0);
                \draw[thin,->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
                \draw[thin,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vfill
        }
        \caption{The cone $\sigma$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \usebox\tempbox
        \caption{The dual cone $\sigma^*$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{$Cone((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,-1,0))$ and its dual cone.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```